# Customize display values for foreign key related table values in AdminJs

Tags: postgresql, orm, sequelize.js, adminjs

I’m newish to [Adminjs](https://docs.adminjs.co/index.html) and I’m having the following challenge:
I have one table with both `id` and `name` columns. Adminjs automatically shows the `name` value for columns that are referenced with a foreign key to the `id` of the parent table. (Great feature!)

I have another foreign key relationship to a parent table that has a column labeled `proper_name` instead of just `name`. I would love to recreate this table display behavior with the `proper_name` column values being displayed instead of just displaying the parent table foreign key `id` values when referencing the foreign key related table.

Is there a way to customize/override this display behavior so the dropdown shows the value of another column from the parent table other than the `id` column?

parent table model:

```
class parent_1_table extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
    }
  }
  parent_table.init({
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    proper_name: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING(32),
      isTitle: true,
    },
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'parent_table',
    timestamps: false,
    createdAt: false,
    updatedAt: false,
    freezeTableName: true,
    tableName: 'parent_table',
  });
```

child table:

```
class child_table extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
    }
  }
  child_table.init({
    parent_1_id: {
      type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    parent_2_id: {
      type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'child_table',
    timestamps: false,
    createdAt: false,
    updatedAt: false,
    freezeTableName: true,
    tableName: 'child_table',
  });
```

foreign key relationships are defined after the fact in the `index.js` file:

```
child_table.belongsTo(parent_1_table, { foreignKey: 'parent_1_id' });
child_table.belongsTo(parent_2, { foreignKey: 'parent_2_id' });
```

Comment: I tried a potential solution from one of the developers/contributors but it didn't solve it for me:

`You can define your title property by adding isTitle: true in the property which you want to use as title (in your referenced resource options):`


https://github.com/SoftwareBrothers/adminjs/issues/1132#issuecomment-1123749783

Answer (score 1):

One of the project contributors in the community Discord clarified the above `isTitle: true` solution needs to be AFTER the column definitions in the options area:

```
class parent_1_table extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
    }
  }
  parent_table.init({
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    proper_name: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING(32),
      // isTitle: true, * not here
    },
  }, {
    sequelize,
    properties: { // put these display options here!
      proper_name: {
        isTitle: true,
      },
    },
    modelName: 'parent_table',
    timestamps: false,
    createdAt: false,
    updatedAt: false,
    freezeTableName: true,
    tableName: 'parent_table',
  });
```